# Laravel recover cheakbox value to php in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, laravel-5

Hi i m working with laravel ,My database containt a table of students.

i show students as radio button contain name as label and ID as value,

```
 @foreach ($student as $s)
 {!!Form::label($s->id,$s->name.' :')!!}
<input type="radio" name="student" onclick="cli();" value={!!$m->id!!}>
@endforeach
```

and i am trying to find a way that every time i cheak a radio button i get the Value (ID of student) then show his informations

so i create a javascript function

```
      function cli(){       
 var studentID=document.querySelector('input[name="student"]:checked').value;
alert(studentID);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","Etd/"+a, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send();
 }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('etd/Etd/{ID}', function($ID) {
     return Response::json($ID);
});
```

what i want to do is to return ID to the same view  and use it as PHP variable to find the student to show

```
@foreach ($student as $s)
@if($s->id==$ID)
 --- show student informations ----
@endif
@endforeach
```

So how could i  return ID to the same view  and use it as PHP variable to decide the student to show ??

Comment: whts the issue?

Comment: i don t know how to use ajax to get data and use it as PHP variable

Answer (score 0):

At firs you can optimize your code like

```
@foreach ($student as $s)
 {!!Form::label($s->id,$s->name.' :')!!}
<input type="radio"name="student" value={!!$m->id!!}>
@endforeach



document.querySelectorAll('input[name="student"]').onchange= function(e){
var studentId = this.value;
// HERE SEND YOUR AJAX
};
```

After that, please post  response that you get from.

Comment: I try with xmlhttprequest and i used return view but nothing was shown in the view

Comment: you should include this view at your page like $('.section').html(response')
if response contains html code.

another way, you can return json from your controller, and parse it on a client side.